# I want randomly to select a cell from a table of values on the same workbook

Tags: excel

I am trying to select a random cell from a table of values on my Excel worksheet. I have tried to use many different functions but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get a random cell address from a 10x10 range whose top left cell is D4 please try:

```
=ADDRESS(RANDBETWEEN(4,13),RANDBETWEEN(4,13))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a random value from a range, say A1:D20:

```
=INDEX(A1:D20,1+RAND()*Rows(A1:D20),1+RAND()*Columns(A1:D20))
```

or similar:

```
=INDEX(A1:D20, RANDBETWEEN(1, Rows(A1:D20)),RANDBETWEEN(1, Columns(A1:D20)))
```

substitute A1:D20 to the range you want to pick from.